# Best way to write for loop while being able to access items in container Python

Tags: python, loops

This is relatively straightforward but more pointed question on how to write the most concise if/any/for loop that accomplishes what I need. I'm rather new to Python, and much more used to the C++ way of doing things.

I need to do something like the following:

```
for item in my_dict:
    if some_var == item.some_attribute:
        if item.another_attribute exists:
            variable = "A"
        else variable = "B"
        print "Duplicate item exists in my list of type: {}".format(variable)
```

I've condensed it into something like this:

```
if any(some_var == item.some_attribute for item in my_dict):
    variable = "A" if item.another_attribute else "B"
    print "Duplicate item exists in my list of type: {}".format(variable)
```

However, when doing this, I'm getting an "unresolved reference" error for `item`. Any ideas as to how I can write a concise loop, equivalence check, and presence check like I've described above in a way that allows me to access and perform methods on `item`?

Thank you!

EDIT: thank you so much for the answer @pjhaugh, that's exactly what I was looking for. Works beautifully! Thank you everyone for your helpful comments as well.

Comment: the `item` is scoped inside `any()` - thats why.

Comment: In your second codeblock `item` doesn't get set to anything, which causes the unresolved reference. But in the first block `item` is set on every loop iteration.

Comment: i.e. comprehensions / generator expressions have their own namespace.

Comment: `item` is a key into the dict - does it really possess the attributes you look for or are they attached to the stored object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that `item` does not leak out of the generator expression scope (this is a good thing).  You could obtain `item` by getting the next thing yielded by a generator, or catching that generator yielding nothing.

```
try:
    item = next(item for item in my_dict if some_var == item.some_attribute)
    variable = "A" if item.another_attribute else "B"
except StopIteration:
    # there is no such item in my_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in my comment - the `any(some_var == item.some_attribute for item in my_dict)` builds its own local scope. You cannot use `item` outside of it.

You can however loop over your dict like so:

Create [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) data:

```
class K:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attribute = None
        self.another_attribute = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}  - {}".format(self.some_attribute,self.another_attribute)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}  - {}".format(self.some_attribute,self.another_attribute)

k1 = K()
k1.some_attribute = 99
k2 = K()
k2.some_attribute = 33
k3 = K()
k3.some_attribute = 33
k3.another_attribute = 1

my_dict = { 1: k1, 2:k2, 3:k3}
some_var = 33
```

You can use a for loop like so:

```
variable = None
for item in my_dict.items():
    k,v = item
    if v.some_attribute != some_var:
        print "No dupe: {}".format(v)
        continue
    if v.some_attribute == some_var and v.another_attribute is not None:
        variable = "A"
    else: 
        variable = "B"
    print "Duplicate item exists in my list of type: {}".format(variable)
    print v
```

Output:

```
No dupe: 99  - None
Duplicate item exists in my list of type: B
33  - None
Duplicate item exists in my list of type: A
33  - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the objects yielded by an iterator in a for loop like this

```
   for item in (i for i in my_dict if some_var == item.some_attribute):
        variable = "A" if item.another_attribute is not None else "B"
        print("Duplicate item exists in my list of type: {}".format(variable))
        break
   else:  # no break encountered
       ...  # not found
```

---

Currently you're iterating over the keys of the dictionary. If you want the items (pairs in c++ lingo), you need `my_dict.items()`.